# Modern CPU for highly concurrent server applications?

Tags: cpu, hardware-rec, parallel-processing, smp

I am looking for a hardware, which must run about 256 computationally intensive real-time concurrent tasks in 24 hour mode. Each task takes about 40-50 MFLOPs, so all tasks require about **10 GFLOPs**. CPU-RAM speed is insignificant. All tasks must be managed by a Linux Kernel (32 bit, with SMP).

I am looking for a **one-mainboard solution** with one multi-core CPU (if such CPU exist). If such CPU doesn't exist, then I need **one multi-socket mainboard solution** (with multiple CPUs).

Can you please recommend me any professional CPU/Mainboard solution which will satisfy such requirements? It is also very important that there are no issues with Linux Kernel (2.6.25). I also would prefer Intel architecture and well-proved stability. I still have doubts that it is feasible at all.

Comment: i suspect this might be better suited to serverfault.  not sure, tho, perhaps SU has enough hardware geeks to get a good answer.

Comment: What's your price range?

Comment: if all conditions are satisfied price plays no role.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can get single socket, multi-core until the cows come home. I have a quad core for my home *desktop* (4x3.0ghz). They are common, and reasonably cheap.

Whether that will meet your compatibility needs is a whole different story. I've installed Fedora 11 (Kernel 2.6.29.4) on dual quad-core Xeon machines, more than once, without any major difficulties (and the ones I had were raid based, not processor based). I've got Fedora 12 on my laptop (which meets your requirements, even though it's only got 2 cores.) I don't think you'll have processor problems.

As for 10 gigaflops, that's [no problem](http://www.intel.com/support/processors/sb/CS-023143.htm#3)...Almost all modern intel desktop processors are capable of at least that.

Comment: Thank you for your very helpful answer. I thinks that any 45nm quad core should be enough! Awesome arguments, thank you !

Comment: @satanicpuppy:  Your name is disturbing... haha.

Comment: @troggy: You know what's even more disturbing? That's what my WIFE calls me.